# Use await Task.Delay() in Winform, the following code cannot continue executing. Why is this?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

"Step 4" will not be executed.

```
// It will not output 200  
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // step 1.
        MessageBox.Show("100");

        // step 2. Create a form, which you can define yourself. This is for test use only.
        var f1 = new Form();

        // step 3. Simulate another time-consuming operation
        await Task.Delay(1000); 

        // step4.
        MessageBox.Show("200");
    });

    MessageBox.Show("success");
}
```

My tests found: Unless you delete "Step 2"  or use "Thread.Sleep(1000)" instead of Step 3.

Can someone tell me why that is? Thank you very much.

Comment: You're messing with the SynchronizationContext. If you want your code to continue, add, e.g., `await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);` after you create that Control (could be any Control). Or write `f1.ShowDialog()`, so the next `await` knows where to resume  -- A Task cannot be STA, you should not be doing this

Comment: Golden Rule: don't create UI on a worker thread or task.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run` anyway?

Comment: @Jimi It seems that I did not understand the synchronization context well enough... thank you very much for your explanation and the first aid plan.

Comment: @HansPassant  I stepped in a pit earlier. thank you for the important reminder.

Comment: @Charlieface No, this is just a simulation, for a better and more concise demonstration of the problem.